# Java/JNA desktop Application Testing

Tags: java, load-testing, tools, desktop-application

I am a web developer, so I know what kind of tests need to run on web application before sending it to production. First time I have developed a service for desktop application.

That newly developed application service internally uses **JNA** library to connect with **DLL** files. Native code of DLL is written in C and that C code is well tested.

Service will be used by existing **UI based** (works in web browser/thick client) desktop application. So we are replacing the existing service with new service(mentioned above). Existing service was written in whole Java.

UI keeps on sending requests in background(**even hundreds of requests per minutes**), it doesn't only wait for the user to perform some action. Although user can also perform any number of operations.

Application is a workstation for building automation. It connects with the devices available on the network. And communicate with devices. At the core those DLL, connects with the devices. But these DLL connection with devices is well tested, so I want to test in the context of JAVA wrapper (using JNA) written around this DLL.

Before sending it to production what all testes should I run on it? I am specially concerned about the **before and after performance analysis**, **memory leak**s, **JNA performance**, **resource utilization** etc. If you can suggest some **tool** that will also be helpful.

Comment: JARs a binary-like files. Do you want to test the compilation to byte code?

Comment: @João Farias : No, I have to test the Java code. Not binary JAR files. I have added more details in question to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks, the edit made things a bit clearer. But I would still say that you only talked about the architecture/stack of the solution. Testing is the act of gathering information about risks in the use of a solution to a problem. Your description only talks about the solution, but doesn't touch the problem it tries to solve. Any technique/tool choosing would be subjugated to the problem context.

Comment: Thanks @João Farias, I have added details in the context of the problem it's trying to solve.